# Improving performance refreshing items every second

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an API that send updates via Server Sent Events (SSE) every seconds for my items.

Basically I have a collection `$scope.items` that contain a lot of information within and every second one item of this list is updated.

What I'm doing is:

```
  var source;
  if (!!window.EventSource) {
    source = new EventSource('/updates');
  } else {
    alertify.error('SSE not supported');
  }

  // Emit SSE for items
  source.addEventListener('items', function (e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
    $timeout(function () {
      var item_index = _.findIndex($scope.items, function (item) {
        return item.id === data.id;
      });
      var status = data.status;

      if (item_index > -1) {
        if (status === 'cancelled') {
          $scope.items.splice(item_index, 1);
        }
        $scope.items[item_index] = data;
        $scope.$apply();
      } else {
        $scope.items.push(data);
      }
    });
  }, false);
```

I was wondering if I'm doing it right or if I can improve this code because the app is quite slow when I start to have many and many items to cycle every second...

Comment: I'm not quite sure... Is `var item_index = _.findIndex(...` looking up the item every time you call it?

Comment: store items to a queue and use setInterval function to `shift()` items off the queue every x seconds and batch update the dom if you store the dom object and the updated html to the array, the performance should be much better.

Comment: @r3wt it will be nice to see an example of what you're trying to suggest.
Thanks

Comment: @AndreKreienbring yes it is.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear: Is it possible that every statement of `item_index` does the full search again? I will formulate this as an answer. So it can be rates by others..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aqb2n5cg/ It may not work. basically this approach frees the ui thread to some extent, except for when its running. you may end up needing to use a webworker if the performance is still bad.

Comment: If the app gets slow then the problem is most likely not this function but rather your expressions, watchers, directives etc.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
var item_index = _.findIndex($scope.items, function (item) {
  return item.id === data.id;
});
```

I fear that a full search is done every time you access `item_index`

I would define a function:

```
  function getIndex(data){
    _.findIndex($scope.items, function (item) {
      return item.id === data.id;
    });
  };
```

And the call it from within your

```
$timeout(function () {
  var item_index = getIndex(data);
  ...
```